# Login from one app to multiple apps in different servers with Laravel

Tags: api, authentication, laravel-8, fortify, laravel-sanctum

I have a first Laravel app builded with `Fortify` as a mechanism of authentication,
And I built second app with `Sanctum Authentication` 
Now I want to login to App2 from App1 with one click, it means without login template

both apps are on different servers and using different DBs.

So I did like this in App1 : 
api.php

```
Route::post('/login_app2', [TestController::class, 'loginApp2']);
```

TestController :

```
public function loginApp(Request $request)
    {
        $res = Http::post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login',[
            'headers' => [
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . //I don t know which token must be passed,
                'Accept' => 'application/json',
            ],
            'email' => 'test@gmail.com', // user with this email is saved on DB of App2
            'password' => '123456789', // also the password is Ok
        ]);
        return response()->json(
            $res->body()
        );
    }
```

Now I developp  `login`method in `AuthController` in App2 like this :

```
public function login(Request $request){
        //return $request->all();
        if (!Auth::attempt($request->only('email', 'password'))) {
               return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Login information is invalid.'
              ], 401);
        }
 
        $user = User::where('email', $request['email'])->firstOrFail();
        $token = $user->createToken('authToken')->plainTextToken;    
        return response()->json([
        'access_token' => $token,
        'token_type' => 'Bearer',
        ]);
    }
```

And I set api route for login method :

```
Route::post('/login', [AuthController::class, 'login'])->name('login');
```

To test I run App1 on port `8080`and App2 on port `8000` 
the redirection from App1 to App2 is Ok and when I use invalid credentials in `loginApp2` method it show me the message `Login information is invalid`. But When the credentials are valid, another token was created to the user but the session is not opened, It seems like I'm not logged.

What mistake I did ? and It is a best solution to do the objective? (Login from one app to another)

Comment: help pleaaaase !

Answer (score 0):

You can try Passport at your main application to allow the other applications, to authenticate using OAuth. Your applications will get an OAuth token (and user ID) when the user authenticates.

you can find similar things from this link.

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/one-login-system-for-multiple-projects-1?page=1&replyId=661442

Comment: same problem.. Passport use access token, sanctum also, now the problem is that I don't know how save this access token for future use. Or  how pass it in header of all requests in one time